# product_alert_stock out of date entries

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

Magento 2 log has been generating a lot of product doesn't exist entries. I was able to narrow it down to old out of date entries in product_alert_stock referencing products that are no longer on the site.

I'm not entirely familiar with this table, can I simply remove old entries in this table? Are they referenced anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can remove old entries, however, it would be safe end to take a backup of existing data. You can see the related data in database table `product_alert_stock` and cron scheduled in table `cron_schedule`. The new generated alerts will be of new products only most probably.